# Make a new array selectively copying, with varying multiplicity, rows of old array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D array with n rows in numpy, and an accompanying 1-D array of n elements in which the ith element specifies how many times the ith row of the original array should go into a new array. For example if my 2D array is:

```
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5]])
```

And my 1D array is

```
array([2, 0, 1, 0, 3])
```

Then I'd like the new array to be:

```
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [5, 5, 5],
       [5, 5, 5],
       [5, 5, 5]])
```

I can't figure out how to do this efficiently, does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [np.repeat()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) to repeat elements of an array.

```
In [174]: x.repeat(np.array([2, 0, 1, 0, 3]), axis=0)
Out[174]:
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [5, 5, 5],
       [5, 5, 5],
       [5, 5, 5]])
```

---

Details:

```
In [175]: x
Out[175]:
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5]])

In [176]: repeat_on = np.array([2, 0, 1, 0, 3])

In [177]: x.repeat(repeat_on, axis=0)
Out[177]:
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [5, 5, 5],
       [5, 5, 5],
       [5, 5, 5]])
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach based on [`np.cumsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) -

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 1, 1],          # Sample Input Array
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5]])

lens = np.array([2, 0, 1, 0, 3])  # Sample Lengths of replications

mask = lens!=0                    # Mask of valid lengths
clens = np.cumsum(lens[mask])     # CUMSUM masked lenghts

# Setup Row-ID array for replications
id = np.zeros((1,clens[-1]),int).ravel()
id[clens[:-1]] = 1

# Finally perform replications for the final output
out = A[mask][id.cumsum(),:]
```

Comment: @Divikar I am belatedly interested in this solution because it turns out that numpy.repeat() doesn't yet work with pypy. This works, but fails if A is a 1D array, any idea how to adjust for that case?

Comment: To answer my own question, change `out = A[mask][id.cumsum(),:]` to `out = A[mask][id.cumsum()]`

Comment: @BenS. Huh! Interesting, didn't know about pypy! Thanks for the update to make it work for 1D arrays.